# What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing a postdoc in France and UK/USA?

Tags: career-path, postdocs, stem

I am concluding my Ph.D. in the UK, and currently I have two postdoc offers one from the US and one from France. I am not a British/EU citizen and would like to take on an academic path preferably in an English speaking institute. Both projects that I managed to get a postdoc offer for are very interesting, and the PI's are well-known academic in the field.

Given that becoming an academic in France requires fluency in French, I was wondering what would be a wise choice here? What are the general qualities that are important for a lectureship position? I am under the impression that for STEM fields, USA is a no brainer, but acquiring a visa might be difficult for me!

Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: The less you move, the easier it should be, so one supervisor/advisor knows the "next" and can do strong recommendations (including the informal ones). So I'd say, personally, go for the one where you aim to stay, so the next transition is easier.

Comment: "becoming an academic in France requires fluency in Frence," you've got a temporary position (postdoc), not a permanent position, so you needn't be fluent.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The question (according to the title) is about a postdoc position, not about an academic position.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The OP wants an academic career. They seem to think that a postdoc in France is a barrier to that career, because a lectureship in France requires fluency in French, but the two are disconnected, as per my comment: there's no need for fluency during a postdoc.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That might be your opinion, it isn't the opinion I've formed.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, indeed, but we disagree on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say prestige-wise, the actual supervisor is more important than the location: A well known supervisor in France will be just as good for you as a well known supervisor in the US, there are just more of them in the US. Of course, you'd choose an unknown at Princeton over an unknown in Grenoble, but you said both are well known.  And all this only works if you are trying to stay in the same field when you move on, if you want to move on then prestige of institutions counts more.

Research in the US is likely to be better funded than in France, and you'll likely have more chance to interact with other top researchers other than people in your own group.

There will be far more opportunity for faculty positions, long-term, in the states than in France.

On the flip side, employment conditions will be better in France: max working times and compulsory breaks are observed: everyone takes a proper lunch and is home in time for tea, and it would be almost impossible to sack you. For the breaks and work/life balance, its is possible find this in the US, but you have to be selective about the culture of the group you join. Unfortunately no amount of selectivity can mean that the boss can't just sack you if they don't like you in the US.

Comment: My point was that there is likely to be a higher density of people you want to interact with at a top US institution.

Comment: @IanSudbery Thank you very much Ian for your thorough and helpful comment (as always!)

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, US institutions are usually considered more prestigious, so that argues in favour of the US. Also salary, taxes, language, your future plans all seem to point toward the US.

Comment: I wouldn't say US institutions are more prestigious. There are a lot of top institutions in the US but one reason for that is that the US is very big (and most institutions aren't that prestigious at all). And after all, the supervisor is more important than the university.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up the role of supervisor. How important is the role and significance of supervisor for future success in Academia? My PhD supervisor once told me your first post-doc pretty much determines your future career? I am sure this is very true, but how important is this?

Comment: @sander: Thank you for your comment. It is always really helpful to have the opinion of someone who has been on the same road and now is an academic!